# Filter array values during aggregation in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I am performing an aggregation on the following dataframe to get a list of advertisers with array of brands

```
+------------+------+
|advertiser  |brand |
+------------+------+
|Advertiser 1|Brand1|
|Advertiser 1|Brand2|
|Advertiser 2|Brand3|
|Advertiser 2|Brand4|
|Advertiser 3|Brand5|
|Advertiser 3|Brand6|
+------------+------+
```

Here is my code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list

df2
  .groupBy("advertiser")
  .agg(collect_list("brand").as("brands"))
```

That gives me the following dataframe:

```
+------------+----------------+
|advertiser  |brands          |
+------------+----------------+
|Advertiser 1|[Brand1, Brand2]|
|Advertiser 2|[Brand3, Brand4]|
|Advertiser 3|[Brand5, Brand6]|
+------------+----------------+
```

During the aggregation, I want to filter the list of brands with the following table of brands :

```
+------+------------+
|brand |brand name  |
+------+------------+
|Brand1|Brand_name_1|
|Brand3|Brand_name_3|
+------+------------+
```

In order to achieve:

```
+------------+--------+
|advertiser  |brands  |
+------------+--------+
|Advertiser 1|[Brand1]|
|Advertiser 2|[Brand3]|
|Advertiser 3|null    |
+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two solutions for your question, that I will call **Collect Solution** and **Join Solution**

#### Collect solution

If you can collect your `brands` dataframe, you can use this collected collection to keep only right brands when performing `collect_list`, then `flatten` your array and replace empty array by `null` as follow:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, col, collect_list, flatten, size, when}

val filteredBrands = brands.select("brand").collect().map(_.getString(0))

val finalDataframe = df2
  .groupBy("advertiser")
  .agg(collect_list(when(col("brand").isin(filteredBrands: _*), array(col("brand"))).otherwise(array())).as("brands"))
  .withColumn("brands", flatten(col("brands")))
  .withColumn("brands", when(size(col("brands")).equalTo(0), null).otherwise(col("brands")))
```

#### Join solution

If your `brands` dataframe doesn't fit in memory, you can first left  join `df2` with `brands` to have a column containing brand if the brand is in `brands` dataframe, else `null`, then do your group by, and finally replace empty array due to advertisers without brands you want to filter by `null`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, collect_list}

val finalDataframe = df2
  .join(brands.select(col("brand").as("filtered_brand")), col("filtered_brand") === col("brand"), "left_outer")
  .groupBy("advertiser").agg(collect_list(col("filtered_brand")).as("brands"))
  .withColumn("brands", when(size(col("brands")).equalTo(0), null).otherwise(col("brands")))
```

##### Details

So if we start with a `df2` dataframe as follow:

```
+------------+------+
|advertiser  |brand |
+------------+------+
|Advertiser 1|Brand1|
|Advertiser 1|Brand2|
|Advertiser 2|Brand3|
|Advertiser 2|Brand4|
|Advertiser 3|Brand5|
|Advertiser 3|Brand6|
+------------+------+
```

And a `brands` dataframe as follow:

```
+------+------------+
|brand |brand name  |
+------+------------+
|Brand1|Brand_name_1|
|Brand3|Brand_name_3|
+------+------------+
```

After the first left outer join between `df2` and `brands` dataframes (first line), you get the following dataframe:

```
+------------+------+--------------+
|advertiser  |brand |filtered_brand|
+------------+------+--------------+
|Advertiser 1|Brand1|Brand1        |
|Advertiser 1|Brand2|null          |
|Advertiser 2|Brand3|Brand3        |
|Advertiser 2|Brand4|null          |
|Advertiser 3|Brand5|null          |
|Advertiser 3|Brand6|null          |
+------------+------+--------------+
```

When you group this dataframe by advertiser, collecting list of filtered brands, you get the following dataframe:

```
+------------+--------+
|advertiser  |brands  |
+------------+--------+
|Advertiser 2|[Brand3]|
|Advertiser 3|[]      |
|Advertiser 1|[Brand1]|
+------------+--------+
```

And finally, when you apply last line replacing empty array with null, you get your expected result:

```
+------------+--------+
|advertiser  |brands  |
+------------+--------+
|Advertiser 2|[Brand3]|
|Advertiser 3|null    |
|Advertiser 1|[Brand1]|
+------------+--------+
```

#### Conclusion

**Collect Solution** creates only one expensive suffle step (during the groupBy), and should be chosen in priority if your `brands` dataframe is small. **Join solution** works if your `brands` dataframe is big, but it creates lot of expensive suffle steps, with one groupBy and one join.

Comment: Thanks for the response, my `brands` dataframe is big. The join solution doesn't quite work since advertisers that don't have any brands inside the `brands` dataframe seem to get filtered out (Advertiser3). I want to keep all the advertisers and only the brands that are in the brands table

Comment: No, the advertisers that are not in `brands` dataframe are still present in final dataframe. They are added in the last join: `.join(df2.select("advertiser").distinct(), Seq("advertiser"), "right_outer")`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not able to get that result with the last join for some reason. I thought there would be a way to filter the brands for all the advertisers before the `groupBy` or in the `agg` somehow.

Comment: I improved a bit the join solution, to keep only one join between `df2` and `brands`. I also detailed each intermediate dataframe for join solution, to help you better understand what is done at each step.

Comment: I think this works! Thanks for the explanation. Only thing is that the `withColumn` doesn't behave as expected for an update I made. Instead of just having `collect_list(col("filtered_brand")).as("brands")` I am turning it into a struct with the brand_name so it's ```collect_list(struct(col("filtered_brand") as "brand_id", col("brand_name") as "brand_name")).as("brands")```

Comment: Can a conditional when otherwise be placed within a `collect_list`? That will probably simplify this futher